# Ayuda con RegEx en SublimeText 3 | sublime-syntax

Tags: regex, windows, sublimetext3

1) Para resaltar una cadena, utilizo:

```
    - match: (")
      push:
        - meta_scope: string.quoted.double.ahk
        - match: (")(?!")|^
          pop: true
        - match: \\.
          scope: constant.character.escape.ahk
```

Con esto resalto lo que esté entre comillas "" en la misma línea. Me 
   gustaría poder resaltar también en esta situación:

```
   var = "    // comentario
   ( si hay texto aquí (esta línea) quiero que se marque con otro color  // comentario
   Cadena | Línea #1
   Texto  | Línea #2   // esto no es un comentario y forma parte de la cadena
   "" Comillas tratadas como parte de la cadena | Línea #3
   )" aquí puede haber más texto que no forma parte de la cadena y deben seguir funcionando las otras regex normalmente  // comentario
```

2) Me gustaría poder establecer cierto resaltado pero que funcione dentro de un bloque, por ejemplo switch-case. Por ejemplo, si yo escribo esto:

```
   default:  // comentario
```

No quiero que pase nada, pero ahora si "default:" se encuentra en un switch (el resaltado solo debe funcionar si se especificó las llaves de apertura y cierre), quiero resaltar "default".

```
   switch (blablabla) {   // "{" puede estar en una nueva línea
       default: blablabla
   }
```

3) Por último, quisiera detectar errores cuando no se encuentra el cierre de una cadena ("), parentesis, corchete o llave. Pero solo quiero resaltar el caracter que abre, no todo. Por ejemplo:

```
   var = "cadena
   var = (2+3
   var = [1,2,3
   if (blablabla) {
       blablabla
```

Debería resaltar solo ", (, [ y {. Tambien me gustaría que funsionase a la inversa, si falta el de apertura.

Gracias!